# The "coupons" tag is being used for bond coupons, shopping coupons, and vouchers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Look at [coupons](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coupons). It is being used for bond coupons, shopping coupons, and vouchers. We should probably make some new tags. I suggest:

- [bond-coupons](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bond-coupons):

  > A bond coupon is an interest payment that the bondholder receives.
- [product-coupons](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-coupons):

  > A coupon is a piece of paper that allows one to get a service or product for free or at a reduced price.

Comment: Agreed. As my wife and I tell our daughter, if you see something wrong, you should bring a suggestion on how to fix it.  This is a perfect example. As a member run site, mods are happy to see proposals along with the note. Your suggestion is likely to be the one(s) we use.

Comment: The tag page says "tag has no usage guidance". Would it be a good start to fill that in with BOTH of the current uses or your single proposed use?

Comment: I guess more relevant to your actual question - What tag guidance would you enter for coupons and bond-coupons respectively? Edit that in to your post.

Comment: Nice work. Any thought on adding a prefix to the store coupon tag. store? product? discount? what do you (both) think?

Comment: I suggest "product-coupons" (based on the definition of coupon)

Comment: Done! There were 20 or so that needed attention. I used the two tags you suggested.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica Thank you! Was it a manual process or do moderators have special tagging tools?

Comment: If we do, I don't know how. So I did it manually. I am on a zoom call regarding school next month, so I needed a distraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member has posted about an odd tag issue and a proposed solution.

I've added the tag "featured" to get some attention. If there are no objections (within 5 days), I'll proceed with this, and implement the advice.

Comment: I left you a message in chat about this last week and today I stumbled upon Meta.  Now I know where these issues are resolved :->)

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't use "product" as discount coupons are as likely to be store as manufacturer.

[discount-coupon](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discount-coupon) covers both effectively.  See [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_(disambiguation)):

> a document exchanged in a retail context to provide a discount on goods or services

[bond-coupon](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bond-coupon) is fine.

I would, however, at least consider the option of leaving [coupons](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coupons) covering discount coupons, and creating [bond-coupons](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bond-coupons), and using tag usage guidelines.  I feel like it's much more likely someone asking a discount coupon tag will not know to look at tag guidance than bond coupons.

Comment: Thx. I like "discount-coupon"

Comment: Should the tags be singular or plural? e.g. "bond-coupon" vs. "bond coupons".

Comment: Singular, I believe.  Tags are usually singular, are they not?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps they aren't consistently.  Looks like they're plural when that's the "usual usage" - ie, `bonds` but `car`.  `discount-coupons` but `bond-coupon` then seems most correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, the term “discount” is also used in association with [bond coupons](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/discountbond.asp)

Comment: It is not clear to me what the issue is that you have with “product-coupon”. Whether it is a store coupon or a manufacturer coupon, it is used for the purchase of products. Can you explain more why you think “product coupon” doesn’t work?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica It's not a terribly common usage, for one; second, it is intended to cover services as well, and you also have "store coupons" which aren't for a specific product.  Product coupon is most similar to "manufacturer coupon", but we're not intending it to be that specific.